# Why the select results is different: Ruby DBI execute VS ActionRecord::Base.connection execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbi

When I use Rails "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute" method, this result will return 56 data, the data is normal, same as the query in the database:

```
db = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
sql = "select u.id, u.name, u.email from users as u join
       (select d.user_id from testthrees as d
        left join testtwos as m on d.test_name = m.test_name
        and d.test_value = m.test_value
        where m.testone_id in (1)
       ) as ma
       where ma.user_id = u.id
       group by u.id
       order by u.id desc"

db.execute(sql)
```

But when I use Ruby DBI, this result will return 54 data, actually this result should be return 56 data, the result less two user data:

```
 db = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:Test:localhost", "testuser", "testpassword")
 sql = "select u.id, u.name, u.email from users as u join
        (select d.user_id from testthrees as d
         left join testtwos as m on d.test_name = m.test_name
         and d.test_value = m.test_value
         where m.testone_id in (?)
        ) as ma
        where ma.user_id = u.id
        group by u.id
        order by u.id desc"

 dbh = db.prepare(sql)  
 dbh.execute(1)
```

Here is relation table:

```
//Table: users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES
  ('1', 'aa', 'aa@gmail.com'),
  ('2', 'bb', 'bb@gmail.com'),
  ('3', 'cc', 'cc@gmail.com'),
  ('4', 'dd', 'dd@gmail.com'),
  ('5', 'ee', 'ee@gmail.com'),
  ('6', 'ff', 'ff@gmail.com'),
  ('7', 'gg', 'gg@gmail.com'),
  ('8', 'ii', 'ii@gmail.com'),
  ('9', '11', '11@gmail.com'),
  ('10', '22', '22@gmail.com'),
  ('11', '33', '33@gmail.com'),
  ('12', '44', '44@gmail.com'),
  ('13', '55', '55@gmail.com'),
  ('14', '66', '66@gmail.com'),
  ('15', '77', '77@gmail.com'),
  ('16', '88', '88@gmail.com');

//Table: testones  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testones` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `one_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testones` (`id`, `one_name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'haha'),
  ('2', 'hehe'),
  ('3', 'lala'),
  ('4', 'yaya');

//Table: testtwos  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtwos` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `testone_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `test_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testtwos` (`id`, `testone_id`, `test_name`, `test_value`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'name1', 'value1'),
  ('2', '1', 'name2', 'value2'),
  ('3', '2', 'name3', 'value3'),
  ('4', '2', 'name4', 'value4'),
  ('5', '3', 'name5', 'value5'),
  ('6', '3', 'name6', 'value6'),
  ('7', '4', 'name7', 'value7'),
  ('8', '4', 'name8', 'value8'),
  ('9', '1', 'name9', 'value9'),
  ('10', '2', 'name10', 'value10'),
  ('11', '2', 'name11', 'value11'),
  ('12', '3', 'name12', 'value12'),
  ('13', '1', 'name13', 'value13');

//Table: testthrees
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testthrees` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `test_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `testthrees` (`id`, `user_id`, `test_name`, `test_value`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'name1', 'value1'),
  ('2', '1', 'name2', 'value2'),
  ('3', '2', 'name1', 'value1'),
  ('4', '5', 'name3', 'value3'),
  ('5', '7', 'name3', 'value3'),
  ('6', '7', 'name4', 'value4'),
  ('7', '7', 'name10', 'value10'),
  ('8', '10', 'name11', 'value11'),
  ('9', '14', 'name12', 'value12'),
  ('10', '13', 'name1', 'value1');
```

Comment: other data is right, just less two user data.

Comment: Can you provide the test data?

Comment: @aristotll Please wait a while.

Comment: You may use  http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide the test data.

Comment: @aristotll I add some test data, I don't know if you want it.

Comment: @aristotll I'm not familiar with this(sqlfiddle.com). It will take some time for me. If it is ready, I hope you can help it again.

Comment: @aristotll I don't know what is the test data like? Now I just provide the similar data structure and statement. Hope you help again.

Comment: Your code returns 3 both ways in my computer.

Comment: @aristotll I'm sorry, I haven't logged in for a long time. What do you mean by that **Your code returns 3 both ways in my computer**? I don't quite understand.